# Firebase/React: is onAuthStateChanged() triggered before or after the then of a sign up function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

okay, here is something really weird, guys.

I have an `App` class and a `SignInWithPassword` class. `SignInWithPassword` gets rendered in `App` as long as no user is signed in. I have a form where users can enter their username of choice, email, and password and then sign up. I have a `user` object inside App's state which is set inside `onAuthStateChanged`. I've been facing issues with setting the displayName of `App.state.user.displayName` because when you sign in with just an email and password, firebase's default `user.displayName` is set to `null`. I tried using `updateProfile` but that still doesn't set `App`'s `user.displayName`, it only update's firebase's `user` object, and updateProfile won't trigger onAuthStateChanged. So then, i thought i would try creating a setDisplayName method inside `App`, pass it as a prop to `SignInWithPassword`, and call it inside my signUp's `then`. but that STILL doesn't change `App.user.displayName` UNLESS I REFRESH IT. Upon doing some logging, I noticed something strange.

I have 3 `console.log()`s. One inside `SignInWithPassword`'s `signUp` method:

```
signUp = () => {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(() => {
      console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser) //log 1
      firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
        displayName: this.state.username,
      })
      this.props.setUsername(this.state.username)
    }).catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      alert(error.message)
      this.setState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
      })
    }) 
  }
```

one inside `onAuthStateChanged` in `App`,

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user.displayName) //log 2
        const currentUser = {
          displayName: user.displayName,
          email: user.email,
          uid: user.uid,
        }
        this.setState({
          user: currentUser,
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          user: {}
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

and one inside `App`'s `setUsername()` method:

```
setUsername = (username) => {
    const user = Object.assign({}, this.state.user)
    user.displayName = username
    this.setState({
      user,
    })
    console.log(this.state.user.displayName) //log 3
  }
```

the order in which the logs were displayed is log 1, log 3, log 2. this clearly means that onAuthStateChanged is only being called after the `then` stuff in `signUp`. which means that `log 2` should print the username that the user entered in the form, right? WRONG. it prints `null`. Can someone explain what's going on??

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a few hours ago, I changed

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
```

with

```
 auth.doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
    .then(authUser => {
    this.setState(() => ({ ...INITIAL_STATE }));
    authUser.user.updateProfile({
        displayName: firstName + " "+lastName
      })
```

it worked for me this way and not with .currentUser